# Private Android Apps do not show up in Managed Android Google Play

Tags: playback, managed, android-work-profile

I have a G Suite Basic subscription.
With the Admin user of the subscription I followed the rather easy steps to publish a private Android App by going into:
https://admin.google.com/ac/home
From here, down in

`Devices (Device management) -> App Management -> Manage Apps for Android devices -> button "MANAGE WHITELISTED APPS" -> button (+) -> in the iframe, from left menu, "Private Apps" ...and so on`.

I also added the App to a Collecion.
In the Admin Google console I also enabled, in

`Devices (Device management) -> Advanced Settings -> Other Google Services -> Google Play private apps:`

TRUE : Allow users to access Google Play private apps.

TRUE : Allow users to publish and update Google Play private apps.

I then enroll a device by adding a G Suite Account : this triggers the (successful) creation of a Work Profile, beside the personal one (I am going with the BYOD use case).
During the setup, just after Android asks you for a unloking pin/schema, I am even shown the list of all "work apps" and I DO SEE the app Android claims is about to install.. ...but it is for the last time.
As soon as the Work Profile wizard ends, I can find (I am using Andoid 9) the two tabs inthe UI: "Personal" and "Work". No track of the Private App there: it does not get automatically installed despite I flagged for it in Admin Google.
More, if I start the Managed Google Play app in Android from the Work Profile (the "badged" version that appears after setting up the owrk profile),  I can only see the basic public apps (GDrive, GMail, Chrome) I allowed.. ..but no track of the Private App.

Is there any other flag I must check somewhere? Can this be due to my "G Suite Basic", not "Business" or "Enterprise"?

Many thanks

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? Facing the same issue myself except that I've added the app on Play console and selected it to be managed from there. Have also done the same steps as you in the admin google console.

Comment: So, I contacted Google and I had mobile management disabled. I enabled it and set it to advance in the admin.google.com. After that, I went through the whole process of setting up work profile on the device again. After a couple of hours, the app was visible on managed play store (badged). Hope it helps